# Javascript if statement in for loop

Tags: javascript

Please help me understand why my code is not reacting how I'd expect it to?

So I'm iterating over the list of values in the for loop, then if they match the value that was submitted by the form, it should return that value, and if it doesnt match, it should return -1. If I leave out the 'else' statement in the if condition, it works (obviously without returning -1 if there is no value matched). But with the else, it will only return the first value if its been entered (10 in this case), otherwise it will always return -1. (like if I enter 20, it will return -1, even though its in my values list)

What am I missing/not understanding here?

```
// reference the form
var myForm = document.getElementById('findValue');

// our list of random values
var values = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,234,255,345,366,900,1000,1002,1025,2034];

// on form submit
myForm.onsubmit = function(evt) {

var valueToFind = document.getElementById('myValue').value;

    // do not let it refresh the page/send a query
    evt.preventDefault();

    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        if(valueToFind == values[i]) {
            alert(values[i]);
        }
        else {
            alert(-1);
            return false;
        }
    }

};
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not letting it search to the end. The first time there's no match, it returns.

You should be alerting as soon as a match is found, and returning `true` to allow the submission. If no match, then return `false` after the loop.

```
myForm.onsubmit = function(evt) {
    var valueToFind = document.getElementById('myValue').value;

    // do not let it refresh the page/send a query
    evt.preventDefault();

    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        if(valueToFind == values[i]) {
            alert(values[i]);
            return true;
        }
    }
    alert(-1);
    return false;
};
```

*EDIT: Your question uses the work `return` when I think you mean something else.*

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I figured it may have had something to do with the else being in the for loop, but for whatever reason didnt try this. I appreciate it, and everybody else for trying to help! & yeah, I'm sorry, I didnt mean 'return' in javascript terms, but you know..

Answer (score 0):

You are always returns, one way or another, after looking at the first item.  If the first doesn't mathc, you must keep going through the loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
{
    if(valueToFind == values[i]) 
    {
        alert(values[i]);
        return values[i];
    }
}
// only return false after the loop is complete with no match.
alert(-1);
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

`return false` will end the loop, and even if it didn't you would gat a `-1` alert for every single item that is not the one entered.

For this kind of search, you should check if the condition is true, at which point you do something with it and `return`, and leave out the `else`. Then you do your "if none of them matched" code *after* the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when found you should break the loop and not iterate next, whereas when not found the loop shouldn't break with `return false`.

However, in your case I would use a flag `found` and flag check after the loop:

```
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (valueToFind === values[i]) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
alert(found ? valueToFind : -1);
```

Another short way is to use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```
alert(values.indexOf(valueToFind) > -1 ? valueToFind : -1);
```